# What is the difference between "keep an eye on him" and "keep your eye on him"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage

According to my research,

"**[keep an eye on him](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keep-an-eye-on-something-somebody)**" means to protect him to make sure he is safe.

"**[keep your eye on him](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-keep-your-eye-on-somebody)**" means to watch him closely to make sure he does not harm you.

But they are too lose that they might be used differently.

What is the difference between "**keep an eye on him**" and "**keep your eye on him**"?

Comment: A cricket coach might tell you always to **keep your eye on** the ball when batting. You might ask a passer-by to **keep an eye on** your bike while you nip into a shop. I wouldn't switch these, though some might see them as interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

Either expression, "keep your eye on him," or "keep an eye on him," can be used in place of each other.

Without context, they are both ambiguous. For example,

"The baby is by the window; keep an [*or* your] eye on him," implies your protecting him.

"That customer seems suspicious; keep an [*or* your] eye on him," implies he is not trustworthy.